# how to protect android app from backup my app .apk. I am using also allowBackup=false. Still i am getting my .apk easily

Tags: android, apk

how to protect android app from backup my app .apk.

I am using also allowBackup=false.

Still i am getting my .apk easily through APK backup apps.

In androidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

if someone give clear definition to restrict these situation.
i will give tick the answer as accepted for my question.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: I think there is not reliable way to prevent this. If there are any solutions, I bet I can find a workaround in 5min or less. If you want to protect your code you have got some more possibilities. What do you want to protect?

Comment: OK, Google Play Licensing, is what you need. You can't prevent the sharing of your apk, but you can check if it is a user who payed for it.

Comment: allowBackup is for whether or not your app's data will be automatically backed up by Android to be restored at a later installation of the same app.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

Answer (score 1):

try the [Google App licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) in your android application.

Official documentation available in these [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)